# How to make a one to one relation in Hybris?

Tags: rdbms, sap-commerce-cloud, database-relations, cardinality

I see that we can create many to many, one to many, many to one in Hybris relations but one to one. Could anybody help understand why so ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hybris doesn't allow a one-one Relation. If you need this case you can simply model just an attribute to your object. Than you have a one-one relation.

Why Hybris doesn't allow it, I don't know exactlly. 
I found this description Here 
[image: Hybris Relation]